# Valid use of <q>, <blockquote> and <cite>

Tags: html, semantics, markup, semantic-markup

Is this valid use of **q**, **blockquote** and **cite**?

```
<q>Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans</q>
<cite>John Lennon</cite>
```

or

```
<blockquote>Life is what happens when you're busy making other plans</blockquote>
<cite>John Lennon</cite>
```

Comment: Why don't you use a validator to confirm?

Comment: @Mr.Alien because both are correct. He's asking about semantic, not syntactic correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `<q>`

The `q` element represents some phrasing content quoted from another source.

```
<p>And then he said <q>I heart HTML5.</q></p>
```

---

### `<cite>`

The `cite` element represents the title of a work (e.g. a book, a paper, an essay, a poem, a score, a song, a script, a film, a TV show, a game, a sculpture, a painting, a theatre production, a play, an opera, a musical, an exhibition, a legal case report, etc). This can be a work that is being quoted or referenced in detail (i.e. a citation), or it can just be a work that is mentioned in passing.

```
<p>My favourite book is <cite>Introducing HTML5</cite> by Bruce and Remy.</p>
```

---

### `<blockquote>`

The `blockquote` element represents a section that is quoted from another source.
    Content inside a blockquote must be quoted from another source, whose address, if it has one, may be cited in the cite attribute.

```
<blockquote>What we have here is a quotation from another source.</blockquote>
```

Comment: I didn’t down-vote, but I guess: You quoted from the HTML5 spec without marking it as quote and without giving a link to the source. You formatted your whole question in a code block.

Comment: He could have cited the spec as a demonstration :)

Answer (score 10):

### Fast answer:

`<q>` for brief inline quotation.
`<blockquote>` for "large" or grouped elements that are all part of a quote.
`<cite>` to give credit to a source.

#### The W3C HTML5 Spec states the following:

[**q**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element)

> The q element represents some phrasing content quoted from another
>   source.
>
> *Code example:*
>   `<p>The man said <q>Things that are impossible just take longer</q>. I disagreed with him.</p>`

[**blockquote**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element)

> The blockquote element represents content that is quoted from another
>   source, optionally with a citation which must be within a footer or
>   cite element, and optionally with in-line changes such as annotations
>   and abbreviations.
>   *Code example:*
>   `<blockquote>`
>   `<p>I contend that we are both atheists. I just believe in one fewer god than you do. When you understand why you dismiss all the other possible gods, you will understand why I dismiss yours.</p>`
>   `<footer>— <cite>Stephen Roberts</cite></footer>`
>   `</blockquote>`

[**cite**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element)

> The cite element represents a reference to a creative work. It must
>   include the title of the work or the name of the author(person, people
>   or organization) or an URL reference, which may be in an abbreviated
>   form as per the conventions used for the addition of citation
>   metadata.
>   *Code example:*
>   `<p><cite>Universal Declaration of Human Rights</cite>, United Nations, December 1948. Adopted by General Assembly resolution 217 A (III).</p>`

Comment: Where might I correctly add the `href`? Would `<cite><a href="">Blah</a></cite>` be incorrect?

Comment: HTML5Doctor shows an example like I have suggested: http://html5doctor.com/cite-and-blockquote-reloaded/ However, I wonder if this would confuse screen readers. In my brief blog post (http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2016/02/new-frontiers-in-communication-systems.html) I have used `<a href=""><cite>Blah</cite></a>` which seems more friendly to me. I couldn't find the "correct" way to do this through Google.

Comment: And just as a bit to add: you can also use `cite` in the `<blockquote>` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_blockquote.asp) and `<q>` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_q_cite.asp) tags themselves.

Answer (score 5):

According to what standard?

If I had read this question yesterday, I'd answered "no, it's incorrect". Indeed, until very recently, the HTML5 spec (indeed, both the latest version of the [Editor's Draft](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#the-cite-element) and the [Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#the-cite-element)) stated

> The cite element represents the title of a work (e.g. a book, a paper, an essay, a poem, a score, a song, a script, a film, a TV show, a game, a sculpture, a painting, a theatre production, a play, an opera, a musical, an exhibition, a legal case report, etc). This can be a work that is being quoted or referenced in detail (i.e. a citation), or it can just be a work that is mentioned in passing.
>
> A person's name is not the title of a work — even if people call that person a piece of work — and the element must therefore not be used to mark up people's names.

Hence, the text contents of the `<cite>` node has to be the title of a work -- not the name of the author.

**However**, this evening I discovered that the semantics of the `<cite>` element in the Editor's Draft has been changed. Now it says

> The cite element represents a reference to a creative work. It must include the title of the work or the name of the author(person, people or organization) or an URL reference, which may be in an abbreviated form as per the conventions used for the addition of citation metadata.

Hence, author names are allowed. In fact, an example equivalent to yours is given in the document.

I don't know which version will 'win' and become a part of the stable recommendation planned for next year (2014).

Comment: Both the draft and the recommendation now agree with each other that an author can be used, but the examples seem to suggest that the author should be `<cite>`d where the title of a work is not preferred or available, which would make logical sense, especially in a plain text (not web-related) document.

Answer (score 1):

[Example of Blockquote and Quotation tag](http://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/8KvXq/)

Semantically `<blockquote>` is used for longer quotes that take up an entire paragraph: Note how the `<p>` is still inside the `<blockquote>` element.

As for `<q>` The element is used for shorter quotes that sit within a paragraph. Which puts quotes around an element.